# Is TypeGraphql with Apollo federation possible?

Tags: graphql, typegraphql, apollo-federation

We are planning to migrate towards Apollo GraphQL, because of the Apollo federation feature which allows unifying multiple microservices behind a single GraphQL API. However we are using TypeGraphQL at the moment, and I believe them to be incompatible. The reason is that in Apollo federation I see you use special @key property

```
/* example from docs */
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    me: User
  }

  type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
    username: String
  }
`;
```

However, the schema for TypeGraphql is automatically generated from classes. Is there a way to still use both technologies, or they are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 4):

Typegraphql had added the support for it, check the examples here https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/apollo-federation

Answer (score 2):

While it has support by using @Directive decorator, it's not quite easy to work with it on a large scale project. I'm currently implementing it on a complex project, and I'm not satisfied with the amount of boilerplate code needed to reference some type from another schema. There was some conversation about adding better support here:
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/351#issuecomment-549156066
I'm planning to add support if I will have time soon.

but it's still not implemented. I've created a repo where you can see minimal example (similar to one in type-graphql repo):
https://github.com/hrvojepavlinovic/apollo-federation-type-graphql